# PIV Card Smartcard not showing up in Keychain after the upgrade from Mojave to Catalina

Tags: keychain, smart-card

My Mac laptop is running Mojave 10.14.6.

I use the PIV Card Smartcard to login and to connect to Cisco VPN and the PIV Card Smartcard shows up correctly in Keychain.  Everything works well.

After the upgrade from Mojave to Catalina:

- I can still use the PIV Card Smartcard to Log In (probably because it cached the credentials).
- I do not see the PIV Card Smartcard inside the Keychain app.
- I can no longer connect to VPN - it give me certificate errors because I think it can not see the PIV Card Smartcard anymore.

Tthis a lab testing laptop. I do have another Mojave laptops that I want to upgrade to Catalina and test the PIV Card Smartcard.

Is there any command line or anything other utility which I need to run on the Mojave laptop before the pgrade to Catalina so I won't have issue with my PIV Card Smartcard?

I know Catalina changed all the crypto stuff, token, etc.  But there must be a command line that I can run that will allow the laptop to still 100% recognize the smart card after the upgrade.